# application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions equivalent for cases where the app is already running?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I have registered my app as a custom file handler, and I managed Mail.app to call it with the attachment URL when the user taps on it.

My problem is that, with iOS 4.2 on the device, the app can already be running, and application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions isn't called in that case.

Does anyone know what event / protocol I can use to get notified that the user wants to open the document, although the app is already in background mode?

Cheers,
Florian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

[iOS Application Lifecycle Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW17)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW17

Comment: ^^ fixed the link. 

Thanks for the help! Bit rusty on my iOS dev :)